# removing Soundcloud playlist embed parameters

Tags: soundcloud

I want to edit/remove Soundcloud embed parameters for a playlist.  I have described this issue more fully with images in this pdf to show how I want the embed to look

https://www.heritagecentralotago.org.nz/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/Embed-parameter-issues.pdf
I have searched Soundcloud paramters but cannot find how to do this.

Many thanks
Maggie